# How can I automate Node.js deployments?

Tags: deployment, node.js, automation, capistrano

I'm looking for something analogous to Capistrano for Rails - https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/

I'd like to be able to run a single command from my workstation that will update the code on my server(s) from a GitHub project and handle all necessary process restarting for the application. I need to be able to control specifically when this happens, not use a hook in GitHub's checkin event.

Are Node.js developers also using Capistrano, or is there a tool that works better for Node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capistrano seems to be the most popular choice.

Comment: i guess it depends on who you ask :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use fabric, it's a python lib.  Nodejs already uses python for some build operations for extensions, no reason you couldn't also use python to do what you're asking.

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.2/index.html

I don't know of a javascript lib that does this, not to say there isn't one though. Fabric sounds very much like what capistrano is, but maybe a tiny bit different in some aspects.

Comment: Have you used fabric with Node.js?